# how to get coordinates of imageview after rotate animation in android?

Tags: android-animation

I'm very new to android. I'm developing a train game. In the game i am using Translate Animation to move horizontally and `RotateAnimation` to rotate my train. The problem is I'm unable to get the coordinates of the while it is moving or rotating.

For example : At game starting my train is at `(0,0)`.Then I rotated it by 90 degrees.

```
Train=new ImageView(this);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.train);                   
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);

Train.setImageDrawable(bmd);
RotateAnimation r=new RotateAnimation(0,90,70,30);
r.setDuration(2000);
r.setFillAfter(true);
Train.startAnimation(r);
```

Now I want to get the coordinates of the train programatically at the end of animation.
I'm searching for this in Google from two weeks. Till now I didnt find any solution.

Is there a way to find coordinates or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use AnimationListener to object of RotateAnimation class

and in onAnimationEnd method of the listener try to use Use View.getLocationOnScreen() and/or getLocationInWindow() method